# SKShapeNode fillcolor comparison

Tags: swift, skshapenode

I'm working on a little game where I have to match some colours. I'm working only with SKShapeNodes; but I cannot seem to get this code to work. I'm only getting the "Different color" print.

```
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.colorNode && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.colorBox || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.colorBox && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.colorNode {

        let firstNode = contact.bodyA.node as? SKShapeNode
        let secondNode = contact.bodyB.node as? SKShapeNode            

        if firstNode?.fillColor == secondNode?.fillColor {
            /* TODO: Update score label */
            print("Same Color")
            point = +1
        }
        else {
            print("Differnet color!")
            /* TODO: Game over */
        }            
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. One of the SKShapeNodes was made into a child of a SKNode containing the PhysicsBody.

Code works perfectly now.